# Marsaglia Normal Random Variables in C++

Tags: c++, random

My query is pretty simple.  I prefer to code numerical methods in Java but often need to do some things in C++.  I like the Gaussian random variable in Java since it uses the Marsaglia algorithm AND keeps both Normal random variables.  It returns one on the first call, the second on the second call, and does not do the expensive calculations again until the third call.  Using the oracle link below (in program comments) I tried to implement this code in C++ but don't know how to write the C++ version of the "Synchronized" Public Method that will allow me to make use of both Normal random variables.  I am not a professional programmer, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

In short I would like to keep:

v2*multiplier

```
// This function is Similar to the GNU 
// Java Implementation as seen on
// http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29
double nextGaussian() {

    double v1, v2, s, nextNextGaussian;
    do { 
        v1 = 2 * nextUniform() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
        v2 = 2 * nextUniform() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
        s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
    } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
    double multiplier = sqrt(-2 * log(s)/s);
    nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
    return v1 * multiplier;

}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem with the code that you *have* is.

Comment: Well the code that I have only returns ONE variable a throws the other one away.  When I need the next random variable I have to go through the laborious task of generating two uniform random variables again.  This time like the last, I get one Normal RV and throw the other away.  In Java you return one Normal variable and keep the second for the next call.  So you do half the work.  This is important for my uses as some of my algorithms take days to run.

Answer (score 3):

Just declare **nextGaussianVal** as *static*, i.e.

```
static double nextGaussianVal;
```

Then the value of **nextGaussianVal** will be available the next time the method is called.  You might also need another static variable to keep up with the current count, like so:

```
double nextGaussian()
{
    static int count = 0;
    static double nextGaussianVal;
    double firstGaussianVal, v1, v2, s;

    if (count == 0) {
       do { 
           v1 = 2 * nextUniform() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
           v2 = 2 * nextUniform() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
           s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
        double multiplier = sqrt(-2 * log(s)/s);
        nextGaussianVal = v2 * multiplier;
        firstGaussianVal = v1 * multiplier;
        count = 1;
        return firstGaussianVal;
    }

    count = 0;
    return nextGaussianVal;
}
```

Edit: A more detailed explanation -- the first time the function is called, count is initialized to zero.  Based on the **if** statement, the calculation in question is performed, and it is assumed that **firstGaussianVal** and **nextGaussianVal** are assigned values, **count** is assigned a value of one, and **firstGaussianVal** is returned.  The next time the function is called, **count** will have its previously assigned value of one, and **nextGaussianVal** will contain the value it was previously assigned during the first call -- that being said, since **count** is now one, the function will, based on the **if** statement, assign zero to **count** and return **nextGaussianVal**.  Rinse, repeat...

Comment: I don't think that addresses the problem, but I could be wrong.  I don't see how the function would know when to return the unused variable, and when to actually run the DO command.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: On the second call would count not be set back to 0 prior to getting to the IF ELSE tree making the ELSE part be unreachable?

Comment: No, that zero in the static variable declaration only gets assigned the first time the method is called because it is, indeed, static...

Comment: Ah gothca, l earn something new every day.  Thx

Comment: I tried the algorithm.  It does not work.  For some reason the random numbers are no longer random.  I get the same Normal Random variable every time…  The Java implementation is not that simple…

Comment: My uniform RV and set to a fixed seed and not CPU entropy if that matters…

Comment: Without knowing more about what nextUniform() is doing, I can't speak more to the problem.  As far as preserving the value of nextGaussian from one execution of the method to the next, though, I believe I've helped you crack that nut...

Comment: AS far as I can see, this code does exactly what you asked for in the original question. There must be a problem somewhere else in the code.

Comment: After having a chance to sleep on it, it occurred to me that you might not be setting the **count** variable to zero in the _else_ section of the _if_/_else_ block **before** the _return_ statement.  Please make absolutely sure you are setting **count** to zero here, otherwise you will experience the behavior you are describing where the return value is the same every time...

Comment: I edited the answer a bit -- though I don't see that it would make a difference due to scope, I did notice that the variable **nextGaussian** had the same name as the function **nextGaussian()**.  I modified the variable name to **nextGaussianVal** accordingly, just in case...

Comment: To me this looks dead on the mark and does what was asked for in the original question. Unless there's just something I'm not seeing up there.

Comment: Well the algorithm I gave generates a sequence of pseudo random numbers.  The suggestion probably solves the immediate problem, BUT it also breaks the number generator in the process.  So I get a solution for a small problem that creates a much much larger one.  That is why I rejected it.

Comment: Did you happen to check and see if the behavior of nextUniform() is correct?

Answer (score 1):

In a more object-oriented matter you should keep that stuff in a "random-number-generator" object. Look for instance at this code:
https://code.cor-lab.org/projects/nemomath/repository/entry/trunk/nemomath/src/nemo/Random.h
The class "gaussian" implemented what you want to have in the algorithmic way you it to be.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the above suggestion is that the COUNT variable should be a BOOLEAN and not an integer.  In addition the stored Gaussian needs to also be STATIC.

I want to thank everybody for their help in helping me arrive to the correct solution I desired.  I am aware that this snippet belongs in an object.  I have my reasons for keeping it in one file right now.

```
double nextGaussian() {

    // Static variables allow the function to make use of
    // both Gaussian Random variables.  Generated by the polar Marsaglia 
    // method This makes the function much more efficient with will 
    // pay off for simulations

    static bool hasNextGaussian = false;
    static double nextNextGaussian;
    double v1, v2, s;

    if (!hasNextGaussian) {

        do {

            v1 = 2 * nextUniform() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
            v2 = 2 * nextUniform() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;

        } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);

        double multiplier = sqrt(-2 * log(s)/s);
        nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
        hasNextGaussian = true;
        return v1 * multiplier;

    } else {

        hasNextGaussian = false;
        return nextNextGaussian;

    }

}
```

double nextUniform() {

```
double Uniform = rand() / double(RAND_MAX);
return Uniform;
```

}

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are using a boolean instead of a count variable, how is this functionally different from what was suggested above?  I'm still having difficulty understanding how the example provided above *didn't* work while this one does (assuming that the definition of nextUniform() was the same in both cases).

Comment: Just curious, but answer alludes to solving a greater problem in the code... which doesn't seem to be fully explained / referenced in your question. This makes things a bit confusing. Would you mind expanding your question some to shed some light on what might be missing here to that greater part? I'd just like to fully see the whole train of thought. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the sticking point as far as I'm concerned is that it shouldn't matter whether you're using an integer or a boolean to manage which state you're in, the behavior described in both examples should be **identical**.  True is the same as 1, False is the same as 0, and the condition **(!hasNextGaussian)** will return the same as **(count == 0)**.

Comment: I was not looking of any solution.  I needed an elegant one.  The suggested solution had bad style and too many variables.  I need this thing to be very fast.  Having too variables named Gaussian (or similar) is not needed.  You just need a Boolean (or int), two Vs, and a place to stick the next Gaussian.  Anything more than that was not going to work for me.  I have slapped this code into my class library now…